# Assign a value to a object #?

Tags: php, object

I have an

```
stdClass Object ( [cart_item_id] => 319299 
[cart_id] => 1 
[nid] => 2140 
[qty] => 15 
[changed] => 1319485739 
[data] => Array ( 
     [gift_description] => ghgfdhfghfh 
     [gift_email] => hgffghhg@gjfdhjk.com
     [gift_sender] => gfdhgfdhgfdhgf 
     [gift_sendDate] => 2011-10-24 
     [gift_title] => gfdgfdgdf 
     [gift_card] => 2130 
     [gift_price] => $26 
     [module] => uc_product 
) 
[title] => Gift Card 
[vid] => 2140 
[cost] => 0 
[price] => 1 
[weight] => 0 
[module] => uc_product 
[model] => giftcard 
) stdClass Object ( [cart_item_id] => 319299 
[cart_id] => 1 
[nid] => 2140 
[qty] => 15 
[changed] => 1319485739 
[data] => Array ( 
     [gift_description] => ghgfdhfghfh 
     [gift_email] => hgffghhg@gjfdhjk.com
     [gift_sender] => gfdhgfdhgfdhgf 
     [gift_sendDate] => 2011-10-24 
     [gift_title] => gfdgfdgdf 
     [gift_card] => 2130 
     [gift_price] => $26 
     [module] => uc_product 
) 
[title] => Gift Card 
[vid] => 2140 
[cost] => 0 
[price] => 1 
[weight] => 0 
[module] => uc_product 
[model] => giftcard 
) ... etc
```

Now what I want to do is loop through each one of these sets (foreach for example) and take the data price and title and assign it to price and title. So I would end up with.

```
stdClass Object ( [cart_item_id] => 319299 
[cart_id] => 1 
[nid] => 2140 
[qty] => 15 
[changed] => 1319485739 
[data] => Array ( 
     [gift_description] => ghgfdhfghfh 
     [gift_email] => hgffghhg@gjfdhjk.com
     [gift_sender] => gfdhgfdhgfdhgf 
     [gift_sendDate] => 2011-10-24 
     [gift_title] => gfdgfdgdf 
     [gift_card] => 2130 
     [gift_price] => $26 
     [module] => uc_product 
) 
[title] => Gift Card 
[vid] => 2140 
[cost] => 0 
[price] => 1 
[weight] => 0 
[module] => uc_product 
[model] => giftcard 
) stdClass Object ( [cart_item_id] => 319299 
[cart_id] => 1 
[nid] => 2140 
[qty] => 15 
[changed] => 1319485739 
[data] => Array ( 
     [gift_description] => ghgfdhfghfh 
     [gift_email] => hgffghhg@gjfdhjk.com
     [gift_sender] => gfdhgfdhgfdhgf 
     [gift_sendDate] => 2011-10-24 
     [gift_title] => gfdgfdgdf 
     [gift_card] => 2130 
     [gift_price] => $26 
     [module] => uc_product 
) 
[title] => Gift Card 
[vid] => 2140 
[cost] => 0 
[price] => 1 
[weight] => 0 
[module] => uc_product 
[model] => giftcard 
) ... etc
```

But I want to do it for each, now in a normal array I would loop through each set ($item in this instance) and take the $item->data['price'] and assign it to $item[$x]->price

But I have no idea how to do that in PHP. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does the loop come from? You talk about `foreach`, but you have not supplied an example of something than needs to be iterated.

You can "copy" the values like this:

```
$object->title = $object->data['gift_title'];
$object->price = (float) ltrim($object->data['gift_price'],'$');
```

...and if you have an array of these objects that you want to loop through, you can do this:

```
foreach ($arrayOfObjects as &$object) {
   // Note the use of & to get a reference and make sure we modify
   // the actual object, not a copy of it
  $object->title = $object->data['gift_title'];
  $object->price = (float) ltrim($object->data['gift_price'],'$');
}
```

Comment: This returns each value one at a time. So object becomes title, then vid, etc. Rather then a single object with each value as a accessible object.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array with `$item` objects try with:

```
foreach ( $items as &$item ) {
  $item->title = $item->data['gift_title'];
  $item->price = (float) str_replace('$', '', $item->data['gift_price']);
}
```

Edit: it works for an *array* of objects. If you work just with single object - ommit foreach and use just:

```
  $item->title = $item->data['gift_title'];
  $item->price = (float) str_replace('$', '', $item->data['gift_price']);
```